# Responsividade Bootstrap - Problemas com grid

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web, mobile, grid

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um site e preciso ajeitar esse pedaço para que fique dessa forma no mobile 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

 Mas se eu faço uma alteração para que fique bom em baixas resoluções, ele acaba estragando as versões maiores. Segue o código desse pedaço:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-1 somos"> <img src="icon-quemsomos1.png"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 somos">        
    <h5>Diferencial de vendas </h5>
    <p> Trabalhamos com equipes de vendas diferenciadas por potencial de mercado, focando totalmente no pequeno varejo, com coordenadores de vendas específicos para este segmento. Contamos com uma equipe de promotores de vendas, que auxiliam nossos clientes na reposição e layout dos produtos nas gondolas.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-2"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-1 somos"> <img src="icon-quemsomos2.png"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 somos">
    <h5>Entrega </h5>
    <p> Contamos com uma ampla frota de caminhões, o que nos permite trabalhar baseados em uma logística ágil e eficiente, atendendo com qualidade e rapidez as necessidades do mercado. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1"> </div>
</div>
```

Como fica em col-lg 
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O que você fez de errado foi na hora de dividir as colunas nas classes:

> Na **div** que contém a `img` coloque **`col-sm-12 col-lg-3`** e na **div** que contém o **texto** coloque **`col-sm-12 col-lg-9`**.
>
> Desta forma quando for a versão **mobile(sm)** a imagem ocupara toda sua coluna e o texto ficará em baixo. Na versão **large** a imagem ocupará 3 colunas e o texto 9 colunas.
>
> Também é recomendado que coloque a classe para versão **médias** com **`col-md`**.

```css
img{max-width: 100px;}        // só para o exemplo aqui
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div row>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 somos">
          <img src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 somos">      
          <h5>Diferencial de vendas </h5>
          <p> Trabalhamos com equipes de vendas diferenciadas por potencial de mercado, focando totalmente no pequeno
                  varejo, com coordenadores de vendas específicos para este segmento. Contamos com uma equipe de promotores de
                  vendas, que auxiliam nossos clientes na reposição e layout dos produtos nas gondolas.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 somos"> 
          <img src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 somos">
          <h5>Entrega </h5>
          <p> Contamos com uma ampla frota de caminhões, o que nos permite trabalhar baseados em uma logística
                  ágil e eficiente, atendendo com qualidade e rapidez as necessidades do mercado. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```